# How to show 'Add to home screen' on iOS with navigator.share()?

Tags: javascript, ios, share, navigator

To allow iOS users to install a web-app I am trying to make an instruction screen. In this screen I have added a button that opens up the share sheet. When the share sheet opens, the 'add to home screen' button is missing (also many other buttons that usually show are missing).

```
navigator.share({
   title: 'Title',
   text: 'Text',
   url: window.location.href
});
```

[image]

Does anybody know if it is possible to show this button or if this is an iOS restriction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the Share API is not the right path for this task.
Right now, Apple, does not make the Add to Homescreen capability easy to find. 
What you have to do is guide the user to use the button in Safari's app bar at the bottom. The Add to Homescreen button is in the panel displayed. You will need to guide the user to swipe to the right to find the button (assuming they have not moved it).

Crossing fingers, Apple will some day soon support the beforeinstallprompt process. To their credit this has been a part of iOS Safari since the iPhone was released. However, they have never improved the experience. :(

Comment: Any Idea why the navigator.share opens up some other kind of dialog? The share dialog that opens when clicking the share icon opens a dialog that contains the add to homescreen button.. would be great if that dialog was accessible :)

Comment: I just checked on my iPhone. The share sheet opens up. It limits the options on the share sheet to registered share targets. I don't have any apps on my iPhone, just PWAs to test, so I just see a few options, like SMS, email and like 4 other default targets.
So the add to homescreen button is not an option for me.
I will update my share API article this weekend to reflect this.